# Creating Google OAuth, Paid Account Needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm trying to create a key and secret that I can use with google for OAuth.  The docs I find on the web seem out of date for creating this for ASP.NET MVC5.  Specifically, when I go to

https://console.developers.google.com/

It's not clear how to enable oauth now.  Do I need to go into "Computer Engine API", enter a credit card for billing, then enable auth?  Is there a different place to do this?

I've been reading the url's

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

and

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

The second one talks about enabling Google+API but I can't find that anymore

***ANSWER needed to enable oauth in google+ api here:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Google+ API. They rolled the "sign into this site with my Google account" stuff into Google+. I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to see it. It's right on the main "Overview" tab, on the far right, first item under the heading "Social APIs". It's totally free. The compute APIs are entirely different. Those actually do pretty heavy server processing, so they aren't free, but all the old standby's (Google+, Maps, YouTube, etc.) are still free (at least as long as you remain below the pretty generous quotas. Power usage of something like Google Maps will eventually cost you, but you'd have to be like running a business on top of it to get there.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt  I guess I was suppose to know it was was part of google plus api.  I'll attach the screen shot of the choice above if anyone comes back here.

Comment: Yeah, I had a hard time finding it at first to. It's not obvious. Heck, honestly, I had a hard time find the Google Developer Console in the first place. I bookmarked it explicitly because I didn't want to have to track it down again ;).